# Magento CE - Force user to buy at least 2 products to check out

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there an OOB way to force a user to buy 2 or more products from a subset of simple products?

For example, if user buys shirt X, he must also buy any pair of pants.  We have over 100+ shirts and pants, so it's isn't feasible to offer these as "bundled" products.

Comment: There is no such functionality. You have implement it by making custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many way, the one I know is:  you can go to `app\design\frontend\yourtheme\template\checkout\onepage\link.phtml` .

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
    <?php if(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsQty() >= $minimunQuantityYouWant):?>//this code is ours
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
    <?php else:?>//this code is ours
        Type msg here, like "You need minimum x items to finish."//this code is ours
    <?php endif;?>//this code is ours
<?php endif?>
```

there is an extension too, not tested by me :)
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/minimum-order-quantity.html